# How to add a border or edge color to candlesticks with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to add a black border around the candlesticks in a matplotlib plot. Here's the code I've tried, which resulted in an error (`TypeError: candlestick_ohlc() got an unexpected keyword argument 'edgecolor'`)

```
candlestick_ohlc(ax2, ohlc, width=0.9, edgecolor = 'k', colorup='g', colordown='r')
```

`edgecolor = 'k'` is unrecognized. I've used it on the `fill_between` function before but the `candlestick_ohlc` won't accept it.

this is the result I want:

[image]

this is what I currently have:

[image]

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/finance_api.html#matplotlib.finance.candlestick_ohlc), `candlestick_ohlc` returns a tuple of lists, one list for the lines, one for the rectangles. You can store each of these lists and then iterate over each element to change their properties.

```
ls, rs = candlestick_ohlc(ax, quotes, width=0.6, colorup='b', colordown='g')

for r in rs:
    r.set_edgecolor('r')
    r.set_linewidth(1.)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! that worked. Any idea how to remove the blur/haze from the sticks?